# How to fix 'Deeplab tensorflow model training own dataset ' ouputs blank image

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, deeplab

I'm trying to train my own dataset just like your experiment(2 CLASS include backgroud) but i get blank output The label image was a PNG format image with 2 color(0 for backround and 1 for foreground)

```
SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
splits_to_sizes={
    'train': 250, # number of file in the train folder
     'trainval': 255,
     'val': 5,
},
     num_classes=2, # number of classes in your dataset

ignore_label=255, # white edges that will be ignored to be class

not_ignore_mask = tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 0)) * 1 + tf.to_float(tf. equal(scaled_labels, 1)) * 500 + tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, ignore_label)) * 0
```

!https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23016323/52344967-fb472600-2a13-11e9-8841-0d0c5c7dde72.png

these are the configuration i tried and sample label image i used

i expected output as segmented but got blank image

Answer (score 1):

So the general definition of your dataset looks fine to me. Still, 250 training images are not much. I never used a dataset of this size, so I can't guarantee that the following helps you...

I have a few suggestions/questions, which might be helpful:

1)  Which label does your network predict (== What do you mean by "blank" images)?. Do you mean the raw prediction labels (which should be "black" in both cases as 0 and 1 are both pretty blackish grayscale values) or the colored image, then it is interesting which colormap you are using (Pascal?) and which of both labels is represented by the black color.

2) If your network always predicts "foreground", then your weighting factor of 500 might be too high. Your network might try to avoid FN predictions for foreground at all costs resulting in an all foreground image.

3) For debugging purpose: Try if your network is able to learn some training images by heart (Test and train with the same images). If your labels and training settings are  correct your network could be able to overfit to some training examples.

4) Make sure the groundtruth you feed to the network really has the two valid labels, 0 and 1. If you would feed the attached image as groundtruth into the network the label 0 would be learned and the "white" object would be ignored as 255 is the ignored label

5) In case of deeplab, make sure you are using a pre-trained initialization for the backbone! In addition, it would be interesting which backbone network you are using? I would expect that the use of a small/compact network (deeplab with mobilenet, inception etc) would be beneficial for a training based on 250 images.

I hope one of the suggestions helps you. Cheers ;)